# Kyocera Hydro doubling in status bar

Tags: notification-bar

My Kyocera Hydro has a weird doubling effect on status bar; I would send a screen shot I have if I knew how. I looked at everything in the settings and just can't figure it out.

Comment: got a camera? to insert image here

Comment: Wont let me post pictures until I have 10 the reputation points and I just started today

Comment: Phones are off topic here. I'm moving this to the appropriate site.

Comment: There seem to be multiple phones called the kyocera hydro, You might want to upload an image to imgur and drop the link in the comments, and confirm what model it is specifically

Answer (score 0):

Volume down and power button work for screenshot

Comment: Wont let me until I gain ten reputation points